# Lua Array and Object Oriented Access for the Same Userdata

Tags: c++, lua

I have an CArray class written in C++ and is exposed to Lua as Array.

**1)** Create a new userdata:

```
int Array_new(lua_State* L)
{
    int len = luaL_checkint(L, 1);
    CArray<std::string> **Arr = (CArray<std::string>**)lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(CArray<std::string>*));
    *Arr = new CArray<std::string>(len);
    luaL_getmetatable(L, "ArrayMetatable");
    lua_setmetatable(L, -2);

    return 1;
}
```

**2)** Access an element:

```
int Array_getValue(lua_State* L)
{
    CArray<std::string>* arr = *(CArray<std::string>**)lua_touserdata(L, 1);
    int pos=luaL_checknumber(L, 2)-1;

    //Omitted for brevity
    lua_pushstring(L, stdStr.c_str());

    return 1;
}
```

**3)** Register to Lua:

```
int luaopen_Array(lua_State* L)
{
    luaL_newmetatable(L, "ArrayMetatable"); // metatable1

    luaL_setfuncs(L, Array_metatable, 0);
    lua_pushstring(L, "__index");
    lua_pushvalue(L, -2);  //  metatable1 __index metatable1
    lua_settable(L, -3); // metatable1[__index]=metatable1

    /*luaL_newmetatable(L, "ArrayMetatable_2"); //  metatable1 metatable2
    lua_pushstring(L, "__index"); //  metatable1 metatable2 __index
    lua_pushstring(L, "get"); //  metatable1 metatable2 __index get
    lua_gettable(L, 1);  //  metatable1 metatable2 __index
    lua_settable(L, 2);  

    lua_pushvalue(L, 1); //metatable1 metatable2 metatable1*/

    lua_setglobal(L, "Array");

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is I have to prefer either Lua code to access an element in the array: **a)** `arr:get(1)` to get the first element, **b)** `arr[1]` to get the first element.

However **a** and **b** does not work at the same time, so either I have to prefer **style a** or **style b**. Is it possible to do **a** and **b** at the same time by modifying the 3rd step?

So far the code I presented gives an error at **step 2** if I try a Lua expression such as `arr[2]`  such that the variable `arr`'s address is 0xcccccc.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an __index method and a get method, just add them separately.

Comment: That's not working and `lua_pushstring(L, "__index");` is actually overriding the method that would be available in the metatable. If I call `luaL_setfuncs(L, Array_metatable, 0);` later in the code, then indexed access works but object-oriented access does not work.

Comment: It will work once you do it right...  You must add the two functions separately.

Comment: As a matter of fact I did, could you please post some code so that I can have an idea how to do it right.

Answer (score 0):

The registration function looks a little messed up.

Normally you would have two meta-tables - the global functions, and the member functions.

```
static const struct luaL_Reg Array_globals[] = {
    { "new", Array_new },
    { NULL,NULL }
};

static const struct luaL_Reg Array_members[] = {
    { "get", Array_getValue},
    { "__index", Array_getValue },
    { NULL,NULL }
};
```

the luaopen_ function merely needs to build the tables with the appropriate methods.
I would recommend also writing `__len`, and `__setindex`

```
int luaopen_Array(lua_State* L)
{
    luaL_newmetatable(L, "ArrayMetatable"); // metatable1

    luaL_setfuncs(L, Array_members, 0);

    luaL_newlib( L, Array_globals );
    return 1; // return table to caller.
}
```

Comment: I dont know what I am doing wrong: Instead of `lua_setvalue` which does not exist in Lua 5.2.4 I used `lua_setfield` and at the end (just before return) I added `lua_setglobal` since otherwise the type was not recognized. A call such as `arr[1]` now works but `arr:get(1)` returns an error "bad argument #2 to '__index' (number expected, got string)". It seems that the string is "get"